# How to get rid of an empty UITableCell appearing top and in between tableview

Tags: swift4, swift5

`I used below lines of code to get rid of the empty UITableview cells` but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `nil` instead of UIView()

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
```